# Fixing an AttributeError gives me a NameError for chemistry GUI program using tkinter in python

Tags: python, string, tkinter, attributes

I am making an application with a gui. The app takes something you were given from an element, like Carbon, or C, or 6, or 12.011 and it returns all the info you were not given. I am trying to get it to run through the window. I have been able to get my functions to work.

As i understand, my entry is taken in(upon hitting search), put in the slot for `givenInfo`. From there given info is adjusted by `takingInitialInfo`. `takingInitialInfo(givenInfo)` is then used to get the list of element attributes in `getElementList`. That returns the result used as the list in `updateLabels` under `getElementList(givenInfo)[i]`. `updateLabels` should then change the labels to display the results

i keep getting " `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'` ". Here i get confused. if i remove the `.get()` from `updateLabels(givenInfo.get()))` from the `searchButton`, then i move onto to another issue: `NameError: name 'result' is not defined`. To solve that i initially marked result as global on an early iteration when i got that error, but now it is appearing again. If i try to assign result as : `result = []` then, as i understand it the list does not fill, and when i hit the search button, nothing processes through.

These issues have been bouncing around and I am unsure where the disconnect is.

below is my code as it is:

```
from tkinter import *
from periodicTable import elements

name = ""
symbol = ""
atomNum = 0
atomMass = 0


root = Tk()
root.title("Elementary")

firstframe = Frame(root)
firstframe.pack()

secondframe= Frame(root)
secondframe.pack( side = BOTTOM )

#Text label prompt for what user was provided in the problem label in row 0
Label(firstframe, text='What were you provded for the element?').grid(row=0)
#entry field
entry = Entry(firstframe)

#place it next to "what were you given"
entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
givenInfo = entry.get()

#Result1 label in rows 1-4
Label(firstframe, text=f"{''}").grid(row=1) 
Label(firstframe, text=f"{''}").grid(row=2)
Label(firstframe, text=f"{''}").grid(row=3)
Label(firstframe, text=f"{''}").grid(row=4)


#if else route to designate each entry of givenInfo as str, int, or float
def takingInitialInfo(givenInfo):
    if givenInfo.isdigit():
        givenInfo = int(givenInfo)
    elif givenInfo.replace('.', '', 1).isdigit():
        givenInfo = float(givenInfo)
    else:
        givenInfo = givenInfo.capitalize()
    return givenInfo


#Loop to run through elements dictionry and make list of the values there
def getElementList(input):
    input = takingInitialInfo(givenInfo)
    global result
    for element, element_dict in elements.items():
        if (input in element_dict):
            result = list(element_dict)
            break
    return result


#Loop to assign each value to its proper designation           
def updateLabels(givenInfo): #returns none
    name = ""
    symbol = ""
    atomNum = 0
    atomMass = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(getElementList(givenInfo)):
        if type(getElementList(givenInfo)[i]) is int:
            atomNum = getElementList(givenInfo)[i]
            print("The atomic number is:", atomNum)
            Label(firstframe, text=f"{'The atomic number is: ', atomNum}").grid(row=2)
            i += 1
        elif type(getElementList(givenInfo)[i]) is float:
            atomMass = getElementList(givenInfo)[i]
            print("The atomic mass is:", atomMass)
            Label(firstframe, text=f"{'The atomic mass is: ', atomMass}").grid(row=3)
            i += 1
        elif type(getElementList(givenInfo)[i]) is str and len(getElementList(givenInfo)[i]) > 2:
            name = getElementList(givenInfo)[i]
            print("The element name:", name)
            Label(firstframe, text=f"{'The name of the element is: '+ name}").grid(row=4)
            i += 1
        elif type(getElementList(givenInfo)[i]) is str and len(getElementList(givenInfo)[i]) <= 2:
            symbol = getElementList(givenInfo)[i]
            print("The symbol for the element:", symbol)
            Label(firstframe, text=f"{'The symbol is: '+ symbol}").grid(row=1)
            i += 1
        else:
            print(type(getElementList(givenInfo)[i]))
            i += 1


#_________________________Margin from main program engine to windo details_________________________#


#answer label adjacent to label Result , so row 2 column 1
Label(firstframe,text="",textvariable=givenInfo).grid(row=2,column=1)

#creating a search button. Clicking the button should initiate the search through the dictionary.
searchButton = Button(secondframe, text ='Search', command=lambda: updateLabels(givenInfo.get()))
searchButton.pack()

#creating a new button, should clear the results when clicked.
clearButton = Button(secondframe, text ='Clear')
clearButton.pack()

#creating a new window to search another element with
newWindowButton = Button(secondframe, text="New Window")
newWindowButton.pack()

#creating a Celsius to Exit button. root.destroy will exit the window
exitbutton = Button(secondframe, text ='Exit', fg ='red', command=root.destroy)
exitbutton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

the elements dictionary i access in a different file is structured like this(the local file has all elements, i posted a limited amount for the question):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
elements = OrderedDict()
elements = {
    'hydrogen': {'Hydrogen', 'H', 1, 1.0080}, 
    'helium': {'Helium', 'He', 2, 4.0026},  
    'lithium': {'Lithium', 'Li', 3, 7.0000}, 
    'beryllium': {'Beryllium', 'Be',  4, 9.0121}, 
    'boron': {'Boron', 'B', 5, 10.81}, 
    'carbon': {'Carbon', 'C', 6, 12.011}, 
}
```

edit: including full error from traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ISO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\ISO\Desktop\sdev140_fall_2023\element_dictionary\elementary\elementWindow.py", line 98, in <lambda>        
    searchButton = Button(secondframe, text ='Search', command=lambda: updateLabels(givenInfo.get()))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

and

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ISO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\ISO\Desktop\sdev140_fall_2023\element_dictionary\elementary\elementWindow.py", line 98, in <lambda>        
    searchButton = Button(secondframe, text ='Search', command=lambda: updateLabels(givenInfo))
  File "c:\Users\ISO\Desktop\sdev140_fall_2023\element_dictionary\elementary\elementWindow.py", line 65, in updateLabels    
    while i < len(getElementList(givenInfo)):
  File "c:\Users\ISO\Desktop\sdev140_fall_2023\element_dictionary\elementary\elementWindow.py", line 55, in getElementList  
    return result
NameError: name 'result' is not defined
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: you have `givenInfo = entry.get()`  - so it already gets string  from entry, and later when you try to run `givenInfo.get()` then it gives `string.get()` and this makes no sens. But there is other problem. `GUI` doesn't work like `input()` in text mode. `Entry()` doesn't wait for user data, and using `entry.get()` directly after `entry = Entry()`  is  useless because it will get text before `mainloop()` displays window (before you even see window). You should use `entry.get()` in functions - instead of `givenInfo` - and it will get string from `entry` after you press button.

Comment: `textvariable=` needs special class `tkinter.StringVar()`

Comment: if you want to display result(s) in `Label` then you have to assign `Label` to variable (before you use `grid()`), or you have to use `textvariable=` with `StringVar()`

Comment: in code `{'Hydrogen', 'H', 1, 1.0080}` chars `{ }` creates `set()` - you should use `[ ]` to create `list` or `( )` to create `tuple` - and this way all code in `updateLabels` would be much simpler - without checking `type()` and `len()`

Comment: in `f-strings` you could use  `{ }` in different way - ie. `f"The atomic number is: {atomNum}"` - to make it more readable.

Comment: i really appreciate the help. I did not know about posting the full error from traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some mistakes or elements which can be improved.

You have `givenInfo = entry.get()` which gets text from `Entry` and later you tried to use `givenInfo.get()` - so you run `.get()` two time but you should use only one `.get()`

But it has other problem: you use `entry.get()` directly after creating `Entry` - but GUI doesn't work like `input()` in text mode. It doesn't wait for user data. It only inform what to show in window, and `mainloop()` create window and display widgets. So this `entry.get()` try to get text before you even see window. You should use it in function assigned to button - to get text after pressing button (when there is already text in `Entry`)

I see you use this `givenInfo` in `Label` with `textvariable=` but it needs special class `tkinter.StringVar()` (or other similar class).

You could use `StringVar` in `Entry` and in this `Label` and `Label` will automatically show text from `Entry`. You can also use this `StringVar` to send text to function assigned to `Button`.

(BWT: `StringVar` needs `.get()` to get text, and `.set(text)` to assign new text. It can't use `= text` to assign new text)

Elements which could be much better: you use `{'Hydrogen', 'H', 1, 1.0080}` and this creates `set()` but it using `[]` (`list`) or `()` (`tuple`) you could have much simpler code when you display results in `Label`s. It wouldn't needs `type()` and `len()` because it would always keep values in order `name, symbol, atom_num, atom_mass`

```
name, symbol, atom_num, atom_mass = element
```

You create new Label when you get result - so you have `Label` on `Label` (because it doesn't remove previous `Label`) but you could change text in existing `Label`. To change text in `Label` you could use `textvariable` or you should assign labels to variables - ie. `l1`, `l2`, `l3`, `l4` - and set `l1['text'] = "new text"`

---

Full working code:

I put `elements` directly in code so everyone can simply copy and run it - to test it.

```
#from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

#from periodicTable import elements
elements = {
    'hydrogen':  ('Hydrogen',  'H',  1,  1.0080), 
    'helium':    ('Helium',    'He', 2,  4.0026),  
    'lithium':   ('Lithium',   'Li', 3,  7.0000), 
    'beryllium': ('Beryllium', 'Be', 4,  9.0121), 
    'boron':     ('Boron',     'B',  5, 10.81), 
    'carbon':    ('Carbon',    'C',  6, 12.011), 
}

# --- functions ---

def convert_type(text):
    """Convert string to int, float or capitalized string"""
    
    if text.isdigit():
        item = int(text)
    elif '.' in text and text.replace('.', '', 1).isdigit():
        item = float(text)
    else:
        item = text.capitalize()
        
    return item
    

def get_element_list(item):
    """Loop to run through elements dictionry and make list of the values there"""
    
    item = convert_type(item)
    
    for key, val in elements.items():
        if item in val:
            return val

    return  # it returns `None`


def update_labels(text):
    """Display result in Labels"""
    
    #print('text:', text)
    
    element = get_element_list(text)
    
    if element is None:
        l1['text'] = 'No Found'
        l2['text'] = ''  # remove previous text
        l3['text'] = ''  # remove previous text
        l4['text'] = ''  # remove previous text
        return
        
    name, symbol, atom_num, atom_mass = element

    text = f"The symbol is: {symbol}"
    print(text)
    l1['text'] = text
    
    text = f"The atomic number is: {atom_num}"    
    print(text)
    l2['text'] = text

    text = f"The atomic mass is: {atom_mass}"
    print(text)
    l3['text'] = text

    text = f"The element name: {name}"
    print(text)
    l4['text'] = text


def clear_result():
    l1['text'] = ''  # remove previous text
    l2['text'] = ''  # remove previous text
    l3['text'] = ''  # remove previous text
    l4['text'] = ''  # remove previous text
    given_info_var.set('')  # remove previous text from StringVar - it will remove from Label and Entry
    
# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Elementary")

first_frame = tk.Frame(root)  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables
first_frame.pack()

second_frame= tk.Frame(root)
second_frame.pack()  # it will put it automatically at `bottom`

# text label prompt for what user was provided in the problem label in row 0
tk.Label(first_frame, text='What were you provded for the element?').grid(row=0)

given_info_var = tk.StringVar()

entry = tk.Entry(first_frame, textvariable=given_info_var)  # keep text in `StringVar`
entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry.bind('<Return>', lambda event:update_labels(given_info_var.get()))  # search after pressing ENTER in Entry

# result labels in rows 1-4
l1 = tk.Label(first_frame)
l1.grid(row=1) 

l2 = tk.Label(first_frame)
l2.grid(row=2)

l3 = tk.Label(first_frame)
l3.grid(row=3)

l4 = tk.Label(first_frame)
l4.grid(row=4)

#_________________________Margin from main program engine to windo details_________________________#

# answer label adjacent to label Result , so row 2 column 1
tk.Label(first_frame, text='', textvariable=given_info_var).grid(row=2,column=1)  # get text from `StringVar`

# creating a search button. Clicking the button should initiate the search through the dictionary.
search_button = tk.Button(second_frame, text='Search', command=lambda:update_labels(given_info_var.get())) 
search_button.pack()

# creating a new button, should clear the results when clicked.
clear_button = tk.Button(second_frame, text='Clear', command=clear_result)
clear_button.pack()

# creating a new window to search another element with
new_window_button = tk.Button(second_frame, text="New Window")
new_window_button.pack()

# creating a Celsius to Exit button. root.destroy will exit the window
exit_button = tk.Button(second_frame, text='Exit', fg='red', command=root.destroy)
exit_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)